# What could be a problem when running a Python script?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

In the python I am starting and I have a problem with the use of example scripts, however, there is a problem with the operation even using arguments when calling the script.
I will not say that this script solves a lot of my problems without servicing data writing.
And I will not say that it would be useful to run it :)

I've been giving arguments and nothing in any way

```
import httplib2
import os
import sys
import csv

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import argparse
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"

YOUTUBE_SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"]
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtubeAnalytics"
YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_VERSION = "v1"

MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))


def get_authenticated_services(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=" ".join(YOUTUBE_SCOPES),
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  youtube_analytics = build(YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_SERVICE_NAME,
    YOUTUBE_ANALYTICS_API_VERSION, http=http)

  return youtube_analytics

def run_analytics_report(youtube_analytics, options, count):
  # Call the Analytics API to retrieve a report. For a list of available
  # reports, see:
  # https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports
  analytics_query_response = youtube_analytics.reports().query(
    ids="channel==%s" % options.channel_id,
    metrics=options.metrics,
    dimensions=options.dimensions,
    filters=options.filters,
    start_date=options.start_date,
    end_date=options.end_date,
    #max_results=options.max_results,
    sort=options.sort
  ).execute()

  print "Analytics Data for Channel %s" % options.channel_id

  if count == 0:
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as csv_out:
           csvWriter=csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',', lineterminator = '\n')
           headers = [ch["name"] for ch in analytics_query_response.get("columnHeaders", [])]
           headers.append("country")
           csvWriter.writerow(headers)

  else:
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as csv_out:
      csvWriter=csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',', lineterminator = '\n')
      for row in analytics_query_response.get("rows", []):
        values = []
        for value in row:
          values.append(str(value))
        values.append((options.filters[9]+""+options.filters[10]))
        csvWriter.writerow(values)

  print "Results exported to csv"


if __name__ == "__main__":
  count = 0
  now = datetime.now()
  one_day_ago = (now - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  one_week_ago = (now - timedelta(days=7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  f = open('countries.csv', 'rb')
  reader = csv.reader(f)

  for row in reader:
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argparser.add_argument("--channel-id", help="Channel ID",
      default="UCJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg")
    argparser.add_argument("--metrics", help="Report metrics",
      default="views,estimatedMinutesWatched")
    argparser.add_argument("--dimensions", help="Report dimensions",
      default="deviceType")
    argparser.add_argument("--filters", help="Report filters",
      default="country==" + ''.join(row))
    argparser.add_argument("--start-date", default=one_week_ago,
      help="Start date, in YYYY-MM-DD format")
    argparser.add_argument("--end-date", default=one_day_ago,
      help="End date, in YYYY-MM-DD format")
    #argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=10)
    argparser.add_argument("--sort", help="Sort order", default="-views")
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    youtube_analytics = get_authenticated_services(args)
    try:
      run_analytics_report(youtube_analytics, args, count)
      count = count + 1
    except HttpError, e:
      print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

I do not know, my question is howling.

When running the script even giving arguments shows the following message?

File "yt-mario.py", line 91
    print "Analytics Data for Channel %s" % options.channel_id
                                        ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Analytics Data for Channel %s" % options.channel_id)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Describe briefly what you have tried? How you run this script? What are the parameters? Show some trace of output to help people in understanding the problem.

Comment: that script is in Python 2

Comment: Print gives an syntax error, which may indicate your running it with python3 but it's python 2 code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Analytics Data for Channel %s" % options.channel_id)?
```

This code is probably Python2.7, where you don't need to put parenthesis around the print statement.

Try running this using Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks, I will check if it works, I have version 3.7.3